# Parsing operators and evaluating them in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, operators

I wanted to parse a string which has an `if` statement and evaluate its output.

I can get with evaluation part but other one is getting too complicated for me.

Take the following examples:

- `if $a == 10 && ($b == '5' || $c == 'test')`
- `if $x != 10 || $y == false`
- `if $z < 10`

I want to get them in array -- that is, the output that I want for the corresponding example would be:

- `[ [ '$a', '==', '10' ], '&&', [ [ '$b', '==', '5' ], '||', [ '$c', '==', 'test' ] ] ]`
- `[ [ '$x', '!=', '10' ], '||', [ '$y', '==', 'false' ] ]`
- `[ '$z', '<', '10' ]`

I guess I'm asking for far too much logic/code but it would be great if anyone could help me with this. Use of regular expressions or normal string parsing is okay.

Comment: You wants to something like, For first condition take two array (one for condition and other one for operator "&&","||") and add this both array in array list....and same thing do for other queries (second and third query)? Please advice.

Comment: What your use case? I think there's are simpler alternatives to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to convert if statement logically into array using javascript

Comment: Disclaimer (i'm the author) .. Check this out https://github.com/MichaelCereda/ConditionerJs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you simply want to parse your string then there are a lot of JavaScript parsing libraries which can do that for you. For example you can parse **valid** JavaScript code using [acorn](https://github.com/marijnh/acorn) into a [Mozilla AST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API). You can also convert it back to a string using [escodegen](https://github.com/Constellation/escodegen).

Unfortunately your string doesn't appear to be valid JavaScript code, but if you remove the `if` at the beginning of each string then you can definitely parse the string using [acorn](https://github.com/marijnh/acorn). The output will be an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), which is not what you're looking for, but you can easily convert it into the format you desire.

Using a full fledged parser however for such a trivial use case is in my humble opinion an overkill. For example if you simply want to evaluate your string then you can use the `Function` constructor as follows:

```
function read(expression) {
    var variables = expression.match(/\$\w+/g);
    var length = variables.length;
    var uniqueVariables = [];
    var index = 0;

    while (index < length) {
        var variable = variables[index++];
        if (uniqueVariables.indexOf(variable) < 0)
            uniqueVariables.push(variable);
    }

    return Function.apply(null, uniqueVariables.concat("return " + expression));
}
```

This `read` function allows you to read expressions as follows:

```
var condition = read("$a == 10 && ($b == '5' || $c == 'test')");
```

You may now use the `condition` function as follows:

```
alert(condition(10, "10", "test")); // true
alert(condition(5, "10", "test")); // false
```

See the demo for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnUh2/

Of course you'll need to remove the `if` at the beginning of all your strings to read them. This can easily be done by using `string.slice(2)` to remove the `if`.

If you're hell bent on converting your string into an array though then that's going to take a little more work, but it can easily be done by using a lexical analyzer like [Lexer](https://github.com/aaditmshah/lexer). The first thing you'll need to do is write some rules for different types of tokens:

```
var lexer = new Lexer;

lexer.addRule(/\s+/, function () { /* skip whitespace */ });

lexer.addRule(/if\b/g, function () { /* skip the if keyword */ });

// match opening parentheses
lexer.addRule(/\(/, function () { return "("; });

// match closing parentheses
lexer.addRule(/\)/, function () { return ")"; });

// match any other token
lexer.addRule(/[^\s\(\)]+/, function (lexeme) { return lexeme; });
```

Note that this lexer expects every token (except parentheses) to have whitespace in between them. For example `$a==10` would be considered one token but `$a == 10` would be considered as 3 tokens.

The next thing you need is a rudimentary parser. You could implement one by hand but it would be a pain to write all the operator precedence rules yourself. Instead I would suggest that you use the following [parser](https://gist.github.com/aaditmshah/6683499) based on [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra)'s [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

We can now create a parser as follows:

```
var relational = {
    precedence: 3,
    associativity: "left"
};

var equality = {
    precedence: 2,
    associativity: "left"
};

var parser = new Parser({
    "<":  relational,
    "<=": relational,
    ">":  relational,
    ">=": relational,
    "==": equality,
    "!=": equality,
    "&&": {
        precedence: 1,
        associativity: "right"
    },
    "||": {
        precedence: 0,
        associativity: "right"
    }
});
```

Finally we write the code to connect the lexer to the parser and generate the desired output:

```
function parse(string) {
    lexer.setInput(string);

    var tokens = [], token;

    while (token = lexer.lex()) tokens.push(token);
    tokens = parser.parse(tokens);

    var stack = [], length = tokens.length, index = 0;

    while (index < length) {
        token = tokens[index++];

        switch (token) {
        case "<":
        case "<=":
        case ">":
        case ">=":
        case "==":
        case "!=":
        case "&&":
        case "||":
            var b = stack.pop();
            var a = stack.pop();
            stack.push([a, token, b]);
            break;
        default:
            stack.push(token);
        }
    }

    return stack.length && stack[0];
}
```

That's it. Now you can parse your string into an array as follows:

```
var array = parse("if $a == 10 && ($b == '5' || $c == 'test')");
```

To see the output you can use `JSON.stringify`. See the demo for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/d2UYZ/3/

Comment: Great answer, that lexer and parser looks nice too. I don't get why the parser takes and returns a space-separated string of tokens instead of an array, though... just tailored to some other code?

Comment: @DaggNabbit Indeed. I wrote the code for the parser 2 months ago for a demonstration. Hence it made sense to take a string instead of an array of tokens and return a string instead of an array of tokens. Since the code was already published as a gist on GitHub I decided not to change it and just `join`/`split` the input and output of the `parser.parse` function. It would indeed be better to remove this unnecessary boxing/unboxing altogether but I was to lazy to do that for a simple answer.

Comment: @DaggNabbit I updated the gist, the jsfiddle and my answer and removed the unnecessary `split`/`join`.

Comment: You and Maciej Sz, both have great answers. Thanks for this lexer thing.

Comment: I made a library specifically created for this purpose, maybe somebody wants to take a look https://github.com/MichaelCereda/ConditionerJs

Comment: Thanks a million, you saved my life :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var operators = ['==', '||', '&&']; // fill the list
var str = "$a == 10 && ($b == '5' || $c == 'test') ";
var expectedArr = [['$a','==','$b'], '&&', [['$b', '==', '5'], '||', ['$c', '==', 'test']]];

function parseStr(str)
{
    var output = [];
    var openParenthesis = str.indexOf('(');
    var toAppend = [];
    if ( openParenthesis > -1 ) {
        var closeParenthesis = str.lastIndexOf(')');
        var contents = str.substring(openParenthesis + 1, closeParenthesis - 1);
        toAppend = parseStr(contents);
    }
    else {
        openParenthesis = str.length;
    }

    var prefix = str.substring(0, openParenthesis);
    var regexp = makeOperatorsRegex();
    var res;
    while ( res = regexp.exec(prefix) ) {
        console.log(res);
        output.push(res[1].trim());
        output.push(res[2].trim());
    }
    var lastIdx = output.length - 1;
    if ( operators.indexOf(output[lastIdx]) > -1 ) {
        var tmpOutput = [[output.slice(0, lastIdx)], output[lastIdx]];
        output = tmpOutput;
    }
    for ( var i in toAppend ) {
        output.push(toAppend[i]);
    }
    return output;
}

function makeOperatorsRegex()
{
    var opRegex = '([a-zA-Z0-9\\$ ]*)(';
    var first = true;
    for ( var i in operators ) {
        if ( ! first ) {
            opRegex += '|';
        }
        opRegex += '(' + RegExp.quote(operators[i]) + ')';
        first = false;
    }
    opRegex += ')';

    return new RegExp(opRegex, 'g');
}

RegExp.quote = function(str) {
    return (str+'').replace(/([\=.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
};

function quote(value)
{
    if (value[0] == '$') {
        return value;
    }
    for ( var i in operators ) {
        if ( value == operators[i] ) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return '\'' + value + '\'';
}

function buildExpr(arr, values) {
    var expr = '';
    for ( var i in arr ) {
        if( Object.prototype.toString.call( arr[i] ) === '[object Array]' ) {
            expr += '(' + buildExpr(arr[i]) + ')';
        }
        else {
            expr += quote(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    for (var k in values) {
        expr = expr.replace(new RegExp('\\$' + k, 'g'), quote(values[k]));
        expr = expr.replace(new RegExp('\\$' + k, 'g'), values[k]);
    }
    return expr
}

console.log(parseStr(str));

var values = {
    'a': 5,
    'b': 5,
    'c': 'test'
};
console.log(buildExpr(expectedArr, values));
console.log(eval(buildExpr(expectedArr, values)));
```

This almost works. You just have to polish here and there, and it will. When your'e done you even would be able to do round-tripping like this:

```
var str = "$a == 10 && ($b == '5' || $c == 'test') ";
var array = parseStr(str);
var newStr = buildExpr(array);
if ( newStr == str ) {
    console.log('ok');
}
```

Comment: I think OP was asking how to parse that expression into `arr` in the first place?

Comment: Ok, you are right, I'll update in a moment.

Comment: Fixed + the previous code can be used for round-tripping.

Comment: How do you have the patience to write code like that?

Comment: You know the irresistible urge for solving something, and telling the computer, that it cannot defeat you? :)

Comment: You and Aadit M Shah, both have great answers. Thanks